# Get substr from string

Tags: php, string

I have this code

```
<?php echo $fileInfo[2] ?>
```

So  `$fileInfo[2]`  outputs:

```
/1/VIDEO/HEY-SMITH_.mp4
```

I only want this part of the string  `VIDEO/HEY-SMITH_.mp4v`, so how do I remove `/1/` ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: To avoid a link-only answer, see [substr](http://php.net/substr).

Comment: Is it always `/1/` that you want to replace? Or is it a more complicated pattern? See `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` depending on whether it's a constant string or a pattern.

Comment: echo substr('$fileInfo[2]', 1);   i try this but dont work

Comment: Please provide more outputs..so will get correct result

Comment: fixed  
  echo substr($fileInfo[2], 3);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string that you want remove has always the same form (namely a number between slashes /1/ or /2/). You can use the following:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/\/\d\//', '', $fileInfo[2]); ?>
```

Where ***'//\d//'*** is a regex that match any number between two slashes and preg_replace replace it for a empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This will return from the 3rd character to the end of the string:

```
echo substr($fileInfo[2],3);
```

Comment: FYI: You know that you can edit your own answer and you can also undelete your delete answers if you want?!

Comment: @Rizier123 The problem was there was a major error and it would not allow me to edit without changing by X amount of characters.